# IIS Regional Settings

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, globalization

My asp.net website locally uses dots as decimal separator (100.55), on my deployment server the SQL Server uses dots as separators, but the Asp.net website changes it to a comma (100,55)

Now the problem I am having is that when I try top do an update from the website the SQL query fails (because of the comma). First I thought ok easy, change regional settings and restart website. That didn't work, so I restarted the server, that didn't work either. Then I changed the .NET Globalization Settings, which also didn't work.

I have SQL Server 2012 and IIS 8.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

go to this link and change your IIS setting for Your website:

[Edit .NET Globalization Settings (IIS 7)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771836(v=ws.10).aspx)

this works for IIS 8.
you must change **Culture** and **UICulture** and set **enableClientBasedCulture** True

Answer (score 1):

```
 <system.web>
<globalization uiCulture="en" culture="en-US" />
```

Use this in we config to Solve the problem convert ',' to '.' .

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET has its own globalization settings, which is independent of IIS,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6zyy3s9(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I've tried that, but still my numbers are formatted as x,yz where it needs to be formated as x.yz; the numbers are either of type float, double or decimal.

Comment: Then you have done what you can do on IIS/ASP.NET side. Check if you have configured SQL/SQL Server properly.

Answer (score 0):

Updating Regional settings of an account using registry:

1. Open Regedit.
2. To get the SID, navigate to `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\ProfileList`

Browse to every folder below and using the value in ProfileImagePath, you can determine the correct user account.

Then use the SId of the folder.

[image]

3. Once you have the GUID, browse to: `HKEY_USERS\<SID in step 2>\Control Panel\International`

Change the string values, for Decimal, change the sDecimal value